# How can I mount a wall light to a post?

Tags: light, exterior

I have a wall light (exterior) that I want to mount on a post. Is there a bracket that turns a post into a wall mount?

Comment: How about providing a picture of the post (or specifying that it's a 4x4 PT post, or whatever it may be), and of the light in question? That will give people enough information to give you an informed answer instead of just guesses and generalities.

Answer (score 4):

A light is normally designed to mount on a junction box. If your post does not have a junction box built-in, you can either mount one on the outside or, if it is large enough and hollow, mount one on the inside. The wires going up to the box need to be protected from damage. Depending on the type of post, this may be done using conduit on the outside, or you may be able to run cable inside the post. The specifics will vary a bit depending on whether this is a solid wood post, a hollow wood post or a hollow metal post, and also on how the wires get from the building to the base of the post.

Since it sounds like OP has not yet picked a post, one option is a post *designed for lighting*. Typical is something [like this from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Design-House-Black-Lamp-Post-with-Cross-Arm-501817/202636904) which is a standard size (3") that matches many light fixtures. However, you are not limited to this configuration, and if you use a larger post you can mount almost any light fixture to it using a junction box.

Comment: Hmmmm. That’s very helpful. I can’t find any posts that have junction boxes built in however. I’m looking for black metal specifically. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where do you want to place the light, on top or side of the metal post? Also, the size of the post?

Comment: A surface mounted bell box may be the best option, if you use the answer please upvote or accept it the check mark.